# Sudoku Solver, small snippet issue (matlab)

Tags: matlab, sudoku

For this little snippet, I am generating a random number, checking if it is part of the row and column, if it's not part of either, it inserts the number. I know it might put a number that is already in its 3x3 box, but that's a problem I can fix. Here's my snippet, if want my whole code I will edit. My whole code is around 100 lines.

```
% Find empty slots, generate random number 1 - 9, insert into slot.
for i=1:9
    for j=1:9
        number = board(i,j);
        answer = ceil(9*rand(1,1));
        row = board(i,:);
        col = board(:,j);
        if number==0 && (ismember(answer,row)==0) && (ismember(answer,col)==0)
                board(i,j) = answer;
        end
    end
end
```

My problem, is when I ran this with a real unsolved puzzle, is
1) It inserted an 11 into a slot, how is that possible?
2) I still see rows and columns where there are more than one of the same number.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Do you have an example `board` for which this doesn't work? Running it on some random board for about 100 times, I have not seen any 11 for sure. Haven't checked all of them for same numbers in a row or column, but haven't seen any on the ones I did check. The code seems like it should work..

Comment: Sure thing, the puzzle I used was the first puzzle on this page;
http://theory.tifr.res.in/~sgupta/sudoku/algo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your bit of code would result in duplicates on rows or columns and why you would see 11's, so this might not exactly be an answer to your question, but it might help you. I modified your code a bit, to not only try one random number, but try all numbers 1-9 (in random order):

```
for i=1:9
    for j=1:9
        tried = [];
        while board(i,j)==0
            newRand = 0;
            while ~newRand
                answer = ceil(9*rand);
                if ~ismember(answer,tried)
                    newRand = 1;
                end
            end
            row = board(i,:);
            col = board(:,j);
            if (ismember(answer,row)==0) && (ismember(answer,col)==0)
                board(i,j) = answer;
            else
                tried = [tried answer];
                if length(tried)==9
                    break;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Well from the test I ran, this looks like it is in fact working. Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate the help. I still don't understand where my code was going wrong; but I do understand exactly what you did in writing that code. You saved me a headache and a half.

Comment: You're welcome. And again: the problems you described truly are a mystery to me. Didn't happen to me once (using your code!) even on the board from the website you gave me.